# EOL Syntax Error while saving a string

Tags: python, string

My error line:

```
desk = 'c:\Users\'
```

I whant my output to be `c:\Users\` but I cant end my line with `\`. How do I make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash

```
>>> desk = 'c:\\Users\\'
>>> desk
'c:\\Users\\'
```